# Algorithms for solving algebra problems?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Are there algorithms to solve non-trivial algebra problems, for example to simplify the following expression:

```
2x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 4
--------------------
         x-2
```

The solution would be 2x^2 + x + 5 + 6/(x-2).

Are there also algorithms for factoring and other algebra-oriented math?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to simplify or to solve for `x`?

Comment: Try searching for decidability results in algebra. For a large class of algebraic theories, halting reduction or incompleteness can be used to prove the nonexistence of a decision procedure. For example, Presburger arithmetic is decidable while number theory is undecidable.

Comment: Do you mean *libraries*? Of course there are algorithms to simplify polynomials - that's how we learn how to solve it with a pen and piece of paper in school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you have given, just a simple division of polynomials work. You can get more information from:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Wolfram has made a career with his Mathematica.  There are other symbolic math programs available as well, such as Maxima:

http://www.arachnoid.com/maxima/

Answer (score -1):

There is something called the Horner scheme - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme

Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that yes, there are definitely algorithms to solve questions like these.

Take a look at [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html). SymPy is an open source computer algebra library written in pure Python. It contains many of these algorithms and the code is accessible on [github](http://github.com/sympy/sympy). The writers have attempted to emphasize clarity for exactly this situation.